# Using @apply built into a Polymer element on lit-element

Tags: lit-element, polymer-3.x

I'd like to use `paper-item` element within a lit-element based app.
Within the app, I'm using `--paper-item` CSS custom property which can be applied to the `paper-item` using `@apply` but since the feature is removed from browsers, it doesn't work now.
Looks like ShadyCSS can make it work, but don't know how to activate it. Can someone help me?

```css
html {
  --paper-tabs: {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    height: 24px;
    color: var(--text-primary-color);
    background-color: var(--default-primary-color);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@apply` shim is only applied to styles in the elements template. It was a bit too difficult to apply it to styles added via constructible stylesheets. So if you want to use it, move the styles to a `<style>` tag in the `render()` method.

Comment: And what if you do not control that element's render method?